# Property bottom is current in the top. Why?

Tags: css

I have green div's and one red div inside a div class "nav". And I want to put the red div on bottom. But it doesn't work:

http://jsfiddle.net/washington_guedes/1kdqwzvv/

---

html:

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

---

css:

```
div{
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar{
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddf;
}
.green{
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: #afa;
}
.red{
    float: right;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f77;
}
```

Comment: Please check [bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom) specifications.

Comment: bottom as in bottom of the page or bottom of the bar div?

Comment: @Sai Bottom of the bar div and at the extreme right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd think that absolute positioning on the red div and relative on the parent would do it:

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
}
.bar {
    height: 70px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ddf;
    position:relative;
}
.green {
    height: 100%;
    width: 50px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    background-color: #afa;
}
.red {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    right:0;
    height: 10px;
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f77;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean you need it floating at the left too? Are you saying that you want the red div below the green divs, on the bottom and touching the left side?

Comment: I updated my code. Run the snippet. I added a `right:0`.

Comment: So I don't need to use float property. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="bar">
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
<br/>
    <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

And moved it up with a negative margin. Just a different option:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ucgmbdqg/1/)

**On a side note**-- I wouldn't recommend setting `div{display:inline-block;}`--that will change all divs on your page and possibly create a bunch of headaches when you're creating the rest.

A better way would be to do it like this:

```
.bar, .green, .red{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

That way you know you're only changing the ones you're concerned with.